# Updated Google Play Games to 'Doge' (v0.9.11) > Can No Longer Connect

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I started adding Google Play Games to our company's Unity games a few weeks ago. We were testing it internally and it seemed to work (most of the time). Then yesterday, I decided to update the Google Play Games Unity package to 'Doge' (v0.9.11), and now I **cannot** connect devices to the service. The main error I seem to be getting is:

```
Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
Error connecting to Google Play: code 8.
DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

I cleaned up the full dump (i.e. removed project/studio names):

```
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:129)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:activate() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:100)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:145)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:sign_in() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:116)
I/Unity: WidgetGooglePlayGames:on_click() (at //Priz
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Activate() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:131)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:activate() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:100)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:145)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:sign_in() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper/GooglePlayGamesProxy.cs:116)
I/Unity: WidgetGooglePlayGames:on_click() (at /Users/cbireley/P
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:193)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:170)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs:44)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGamesProxy:authenticate() (at //Project/Assets/Scripts/Helper
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Creating real IPlayGamesClient
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesClientFactory:GetPlatformPlayGamesClient(PlayGamesClientConfiguration) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/PlayGamesClientFactory.cs:32)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1, Boolean) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:194)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform:Authenticate(Action`1) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesPlatform.cs:170)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser:Authenticate(Action`1) (at /Users/cbireley/P4Depot_cbireley/Dev/
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/GamesUnitySDK: Performing Android initialization of the GPG SDK
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
E/GamesNativeSDK: Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.studio.project/app_.gpg.classloader/4da25210572e7e07ea67142ded62c42e.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
W/PopupManager: You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
I/GamesNativeSDK: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
I/GamesNativeSDK: Connecting to Google Play...
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Entering state: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:333)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:.ctor(RealtimeManager, RealTimeMultiplayerListener) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:304)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:42)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMul
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: BeforeRoomCreateStartedState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.State:OnStateEntered() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:500)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:334)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:.ctor(RealtimeManager, RealTimeMultiplayerListener) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:304)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerCl
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Entering state: ShutdownState
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:333)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:43)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:.ctor(NativeClient, RealtimeManager) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:38)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient:InitializeGameS
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: ShutdownState.OnStateEntered: Defaulting to no-op.
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.State:OnStateEntered() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:500)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.RoomSession:EnterState(State) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:334)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:GetTerminatedSession() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient.cs:43)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeRealtimeMultiplayerClient:.ctor(NativeClient, 
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so 0x42a492a8
D/dalvikvm: Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.studio.project-24/lib/libgpg.so' already loaded in same CL 0x42a492a8
V/GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
I/GamesNativeSDK: Error connecting to Google Play: code 8.
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
I/Unity:  
I/Unity: (Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/GamesNativeSDK: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
I/GamesNativeSDK: Connecting to Google Play...
V/GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
I/GamesNativeSDK: Error connecting to Google Play: code 8.
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
I/Unity:  
I/Unity: (Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/AndroidManagedGenerated/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 49)
I/Unity:  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/30/14 15:27:43 -06:00 DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
I/Unity: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.Logger:d(String) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/Logger.cs:46)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.Native.<InvokeCallbackOnGameThread>c__AnonStorey69:<>m__9() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeClient.cs:121)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:<Update>m__3(Action) (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:98)
I/Unity: System.Collections.Generic.List`1:ForEach(Action`1)
I/Unity: GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at //Project/Assets/GooglePlayGames/OurUtils/PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:98)
D/dalvikvm: threadid=31: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
V/GamesNativeSDK: Detaching from JVM on thread main_dispatch
I/System.out: pool-4-thread-1 calls detatch()
```

Here is my .cs code:

```
  //============================================================================
  public void sign_in ()
  {
    IsUpdatingPermitted = false;
    authenticate();
  }

  //============================================================================
  public void sign_out ()
  {
    if (IsActivated == false) {
      activate();
    }

    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();
    AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    IsUpdatingPermitted = false;
  }

  //============================================================================
  public void on_setup ()
  {
    if (AutomaticAuthentication) {
      authenticate();
    }
  }

  //============================================================================
  public void activate ()
  {
    log_status(string.Format("Activating...\nNetworkStateManager.isConnected: {0}\nIsActivated: {1}", NetworkStateManager.isConnected, IsActivated));

    if (NetworkStateManager.isConnected == false || IsActivated) {
      return;
    }

    SaveSystem.on_save_game_state_finished_event += on_save_game_state_finished_listener;

    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
      .EnableSavedGames()      
        .Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    IsActivated = true;
  }

  //============================================================================
  public void authenticate ()
  {
    log_status(string.Format("Authenticating...\n IsActivated: {0}\nIsAuthenticated: {1}", IsActivated, IsAuthenticated));

    if (IsActivated == false) {
      activate();
    }

    if (IsAuthenticated) {
      return;
    }

    IsTransactionPending = true;
    Social.localUser.Authenticate(on_social_authenticated);
  }

  //============================================================================
  private void on_social_authenticated (bool success)
  {
    log_status("Authentication: " + success);

    IsTransactionPending = false;
    AutomaticAuthentication = success;

    if (success) {
      open_saved_game();
      Achievements.on_setup();
    } else if (Application.isEditor) {
      editor_load_cloud_save();
    }

    if (on_social_authenticated_event != null) {
      on_social_authenticated_event(success);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It appears I have narrowed it down to:

".EnableSavedGames()"

And the fact that it was not toggled in the Developer Console (thanks horrible lack of documentation).

Comment: However, now the issue lies in the fact that I get the following:

  
"Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console."
 

Which makes *zero* sense since I have just toggled that setting to even get connected in the first place.

Thoughts? Assistance?